# SQL - Results from multiple rows in single table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table named `LEDGER`. It has three columns named `PATID`, `CODE` and `TRANDATE`.

Example data:

```
PATID  CODE   TRANDATE
1      Z1110  07-15-1970 
1      D3330  07-15-1970
1      Z0330  07-15-1970
2      Z1298  07-20-1970
2      Z0987  07-20-1970
2      Z0330  07-20-1970
2      D1092  07-20-1970
3      Z0330  08-20-1980
3      Z1110  02-11-1982
```

I need a query that returns `PATID` if they have the `CODE` of `Z0330` but not `Z1110` *and* both codes appear on the same `TRANDATE`. I only want one `PATID` to return if this condition exists. In the example above, the output should be:

```
PATID  CODE   TRANDATE
2      Z0330  07-20-1970
3      Z0330  07-20-1980
```

How can I write a query to do this?

Comment: This was the solution: SELECT *
FROM LEDGER t
WHERE CODE = 'Z0330'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM LEDGER
WHERE PATID = t.PATID
AND CODE = 'Z1110'
AND TRANDATE = t.TRANDATE
)

Answer (score 3):

You can get what you want using aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select patid, 'Z0330' as code, transdate
from example
group by patid, transdate
having sum(case when code = 'Z0330' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when code = 'Z1110' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: I get the "An expression of non-boolean type specified" error (using MSSQL) Also, will this fix the date issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this, first select trandates where have code 'z1110' and then select rows that have no transadate in prev query.

```
SELECT * FROM LEDGER WHERE TRANDATE NOT IN(
    SELECT TRANDATE FROM LEDGER WHERE CODE = 'Z1110'
)
AND CODE = 'Z3330'
```

Comment: Do you believe SQL allows **two** `WHERE` clauses in the **same** statement?  C'mon.

Comment: Look at your outer query and stop shouting.  I assume you already learned how to count to two.

Comment: my caps was ON and i'm not shouting, excuse me

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT PATID, TRANDATE
FROM LEDGER L1
where not exists (select 1 from LEDGER L2
              where L1.TRANDATE = L2.TRANDATE
                and L2.CODE = 'Z1110' );
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9b6f/22)

Comment: The returns EVERY PATID that doesn't have CODE Z1110. Opposite of what I need, but I like the code. Just starting to learning SQL (obviously) and I like breaking these down so I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. If you want old day of each month then change the order to ASC. Currently the query retrieves the latest day of each month.

Example is available here [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd514/20)

```
;WITH cte_Result AS 
(
    SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                 PARTITION BY CODE,
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), TRANDATE, 120) ORDER BY TRANDATE DESC
             ) AS ID,
             PATID,
             CODE,
             TRANDATE
    FROM     LEDGER
    WHERE    CODE = 'Z0330'
)
SELECT   PATID,
         CODE,
         TRANDATE
FROM     cte_Result
WHERE    ID = 1
```